# C language parse file's detail

Tags: c, parsing

I'm a beginner with C.

I want to parse all the source code (e.g., `*.c`, `*.h`) under a directory.

I want to know the file name, size, how many lines in the source.

After searching, I can parse one file's detail (to get how many lines in the source). I can also use `system()` to know the size and file name, or file list in the directory (without size).

But I have no idea about how to combine all these into one program, so I'm looking for guidance on that.

Thanks all!

---

below is my code for now

have no idea about next step..

```
int main (void){

    DIR *dp;
    FILE *fp;
    struct dirent *ep;


    dp = opendir ("./");
    fp = fopen ("output.txt", "w");
    if (dp != NULL)
    {
            while (ep = readdir (dp))

            fprintf(fp,"%s\n", ep->d_name);

            (void) closedir (dp);
    }
    else
    perror ("Couldn't open the directory");

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Just use `wc dir/*`, or `wc dir/*.[hc]`

Comment: @Tom, since this is a development site and the OP is a beginning C programmer, it may be (just *may* be) that they're trying to write their own program to do this :-)

Comment: Do you want to parse them, or to compile them?

Comment: parse, want to  make file that list out all the *.c *.h in the folder and size and line  of these file

Answer (score 3):

Here's the things you need to look in to:

- how to iterate over file names, such as with `opendir()`, `readdir()` and so on, including `while` statement for the actual iteration of course.
- how to get file details, such as with `fstat()`.
- how to open and read files, such as with `fopen()`, `fgetchar()` and `fclose()`, including how to recognise line end characters with `if`.

That should be the tools you need to start the job, I'd suggest looking in to them then trying to construct your program. *Specific* problems with the program can then be bought to our attention in other questions.

Note that the examples given above (specifically those in the `opendir` bullet point) may be platform-specific. If they're not available, you'll need to find equivalents for your platform since standard C does not provide that functionality.

Comment: Great. But this is Linux or POSIX. Standard C99 does not know about directories!!

Comment: @Basile, hence the phrase "such as". Obviously, if you're running on a non-POSIX environment, you need to find the correct way. That doesn't invalidate the answer which is giving what you need to find, along with an example. I'll clarify.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of examples on Stack Overflow. The biggest hurdle when learning how to process directories is take it piece-by-piece. There are many options to consider for `scandir` or `opendir/readdir`, and it will take a while to soak in. There is a simple example in *man scandir* if you want to go that route. `stat` is another piece to the puzzle. Just search this site. If you are still stuck, let us know.